# unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray' while plotting a 3D chart

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, optimization, data-visualization

So I am plotting a 3D chart and I have made a cost function and some data using numpy but when I actually try to plot the data in chart I get the error `unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'`. I'm still a beginner and I'm clueless about the error.

Following is my source code:

```
def f(x, y):
    r = 3**{-x**2 - y**2}
    return 1 / r + 1
# Make data for x and y 

x_4 = np.linspace(start = -2, stop = 2, num = 200)
y_4 = np.linspace(start = -2, stop = 2, num = 200)


x_4, y_4 = np.meshgrid(x_4, y_4)

# Creating a 3D chart

fig = plt.figure(figsize = [16, 12])
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

ax.plot_surface(x_4, y_4, f(x_4, y_4))

plt.show()
```

And following is the error I'm getting:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-bd526ad2cdcb> in <module>
      4 ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
      5 
----> 6 ax.plot_surface(x_4, y_4, f(x_4, y_4))
      7 
      8 plt.show()

<ipython-input-24-a27a21ef332f> in f(x, y)
      1 def f(x, y):
----> 2     r = 3**{-x**2 - y**2}
      3     return 1 / r + 1

TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

I even changed the array type to 2D but still it is giving type error and I have no clue why. Thanks in advance.

Comment: A ``set`` (via ``{}``) is not a valid as a power of an integer. Did you mean to use ``()`` instead?

Comment: Yes it was just a typo. My bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write `r = 3**(-x**2 - y**2)`. `{...}` will be a `set`.